# Terminal is blank on second user account

Tags: command-line, gnome-terminal

This is a weird problem: after moving /home to a new disk, my gnome terminal does not execute any command. It is just blank: It does not contain the usual

```
name@computer:~#
```

I can enter text in it but nothing is executed. I don't have this problem on my main user account or new user account that I just created.

I also installed and tested other consols but they had the same problem.

What could be wrong and how can I fix it?

Comment: there're some hidden files in /home, e.g. .bashrc, .bash_profile. maybe you don't move all of them to the new disk.

Comment: well I can see .bashrc and other hidden files in /home/user2

Comment: @sgx1: Actually after copying .bashrc from /home/user1 to /home/user2, the terminal works fine for user2. So you can answer and I accept it. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem can occur when some of [shell initialization files](http://linux.die.net/Bash-Beginners-Guide/sect_03_01.html) (like `.bashrc`, `.profile`, `.bash_logout`) which are hidden files are missing, empty or corrupted. To solve this problem, from the main user account run the following commands from terminal as superuser:

```bsh
# copy .bashrc .profile, .bash_logout files from /etc/skel to the new home directory of user2
sudo cp /etc/skel/.bashrc /etc/skel/.profile /etc/skel/.bash_logout /home/user2
# be sure that user2 is the owner of the previous copied files
sudo chown user2:user2 /home/user2/.bashrc /home/user2/.profile /home/user2/.bash_logout
```