# Question about something appearing in my Terminal

Tags: command-line, bash, bashrc

After I moved from Windows to Ubuntu I liked to try out every new app I found so I decided to install Betty (a Siri like alternative for Ubuntu). I used the PPA given by Webupd8 site and the last thing needed was to add the path to the main Betty file using this command:

```
echo "alias betty=\"~/betty/main.rb\"" >> ~/.bashrc
source ~/.bashrc
```

For some reasons it didn't worked, I couldn't install it properly, so I removed everything added by these PPAs. But since then every time I open my terminal it shows these:

```
bash: alias: source: not found

bash: alias: /home/usrname/.bashrc: not found
```

Can I remove that? It's not a big deal, my terminal works fine, it just annoys me.

Comment: Run `tail -5 ~/.bashrc`.This will print the last five lines of your `.bashrc` file, which could be helpful in solving the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem can occur when `.bashrc` file (which is a hidden file) is missing or corrupted. To solve this problem, run the following command from terminal as your normal user to copy the default `.bashrc` file from `/etc/skel` to the home directory:

```
cp /etc/skel/.bashrc ~
```

Comment: I've de-sudo'd this because I can't see that it would need it. I could be missing something so let me know.

Comment: @Oli Thx, this is happening when you [copy content](http://askubuntu.com/a/406855/147044) in a sleeping state... :D